# Crear un json en PHP

Tags: php

Necesito formar un json con la siguiente estructura

```
{"1": {
    "44444": "2",
    "54": "1",
    "472": "1"
},

"3": {
    "33333": "2"
},

"31089": {
    "888": "2",
    "6666": "1"
} }
```

donde los índices "1", "3" y "31089" los obtengo de una consulta con los usuarios y "44444": "2" se obtienen de otra consulta y son el no_evento y participaciones.

Tengo problemas con formarlo y lo que he logrado lo he hecho con el siguiente código:

```
foreach ($n_usuarios as $usrs){
   $idu_u = $usrs["id_usuario"];    

   array_push($participaciones, $idu_u);

   foreach ($n_participaciones as $part){

       $idu_p = $part["id_usuario"];

       if ($idu_u != $idu_p) {
           $temp[$part["id_evento"]] = $part["id_participacion"];
       } else {
        array_push($participaciones, $temp);
        $temp = "";
       }
    }}
```

lo que me resulta en lo siguiente:

1

> {6347: "1", 6348: "1", 6349: "1", 6352: "1", 6353: "1", 6354: "1",
>   6356: "1", 6374: "1", 6376: "1", 6377: "1", 25271: "1", 25272: "1",
>   25273: "1", 25274: "1"}

ALguien me pudiera decir cómo formo mi json

Comment: ¿Los datos están en una base de datos?

Comment: Sí, son de una base de datos

Comment: Pasanos lo valores de los array

Comment: Se puede crear el JSON también desde la consulta SQL. Dependiendo de la versión de base de datos que tengas, ya traen funciones para JSON, o se puede hacer con `CONCAT`, y agrupando los datos.

Answer (score 1):

Muy fácil primero crea tu llena array normalmente como cualquier otro array.

Ya que lo tengas lleno con los datos que deseas solo aplica la funcion json_encode

```
$n_usuarios = [1,3,31089];
$n_participaciones = [44444=>2,54=>1,472=>1];
$json = [];

foreach ($n_usuarios as $usrs){
   $idu_u = $usrs;    

  $json[$idu_u] = [];

   /*Aqui deverias hacer una consulta para que solo te traiga las participaciones de ese usuario
    $$n_participaciones = $model->get("Select no_evento,participaciones where id_usuario=$idu_u ");
   */
   foreach ($n_participaciones as $key=>$part){

       $json[$idu_u][]= [$key=>$part];

    }
}

 echo json_encode($json);
```

Y listo ya tienes creado tu json a partir  de tu array

me resulta algo asi:

```
{
    "1":[
        {"44444":2},
        {"54":1},
        {"472":1}
    ],
    "3":[
        {"44444":2},
        {"54":1},
        {"472":1}
    ],
    "31089":[
        {"44444":2},
        {"54":1},
        {"472":1}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con este código, te explico; no necesitas el array_push si no necesitas el valor de retorno de la función y de hecho es mas rápido ve: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php

y tienes un error aqui :

```
   if ($idu_u != $idu_p) {
       $temp[$part["id_evento"]] = $part["id_participacion"];
   } else {
    array_push($participaciones, $temp);
    $temp = "";
   }
```

Lo que haces aquí es comparar los id de las dos consultas y si son **diferentes** lo asignas a `$temp`, y si son iguales metes `$temp` al arreglo `$participaciones`

dicho esto puedes reducir tu código así y tal vez así te funcione:

```
foreach ($n_usuarios as $usrs){

   $idu_u = $usrs["id_usuario"];  

   foreach ($n_participaciones as $part){

       $idu_p = $part["id_usuario"];

       if ($idu_u == $idu_p) { // evaluamos si el id es igual

           // y si es verdadero introducimos asi al array $participaciones

           $participaciones[$idu_u][$part["id_evento"]]=$part["id_participacion"];  
       }         
    }}          


    // por ultimo usas json_enconde() para darle el formato de json al arreglo
    echo json_encode($participaciones);
```

Comment: Hola stre_leon, me ha funcionado tu recomendación, lo he hecho de la siguiente manera:

foreach ($n_participaciones as $part){        
 $temp[$idu_u][$part["id_evento"]]=$part["id_participacion"];    
}   
$json[] = $temp;

y obtengo lo siguiente:

Comment: 21711: {6347: "1", 6348: "1", 6349: "1", 6352: "1", 6353: "1", 6354: "1", 6355: "1", 6356: "1", 6366: "1", 6367: "1"}

21653: {6347: "2", 6348: "1", 6349: "1", 6352: "1", 6353: "2", 6354: "1", 6356: "1"}

16637: {6347: "1", 6348: "1", 6349: "1", 6352: "1", 6353: "1", 6354: "1", 6355: "1", 6356: "1", 6379: "1", 25278: "1"}

ahora, no sé cómo puedo obtener cada uno de los elementos. ¿Tienes ídea de cómo se hace?

Comment: Estoy tratando de leerlo con un each, pero no puedo obtener los elementos por separado:

$.each(accesoActividad, function(key, acceso){
    console.log(acceso);
}) 

me arroja sólo el elemento completo: 
21653: {6347: "2", 6348: "1", 6349: "1", 6352: "1", 6353: "2", 6354: "1", 6356: "1"}

Comment: Anteriormente he trabajado con json's con indice incremental y puedo obtener cada elemento, algo como esto:
{
 "members": [{
   "name": "Molecule Man",
   "age": 29,
   "secretIdentity": "Dan Jukes"
  },
  {
   "name": "Madame Uppercut",
   "age": 39,
   "secretIdentity": "Jane Wilson"
  }
 ]
} 
y por medio de la etiqueta obtengo el dato, pero ahora no tengo idea de cómo hacerlo.